# Difference between growth formulas

Tags: calculus, exponentiation

What is the difference between $$N = N_0 \cdot e^{kt}$$ and

$$N= N_0(1+r)^n$$

I'm trying to find the best formula to calculate population growth and sources seem to vary between these two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is in a continuous time setup, the second one in a discrete time setup. Both with a constant growth rate.

Comment: But one grows slower than the other? This implies that continuous setups grow faster than discrete ones??

Comment: No. It depends on the values of $k$ and $r$.

Comment: With the first definition $N(n+1)/N(n)= e^k$ and in the second case $N(n+1)/N(n)= 1+r$

Comment: Cool...Can you tell me...I've got a bug that multiplies by about 1.7 each month and takes 2 months to mature to have children of its own.

I start with 1 bug and if I draw a diagram and calculate, I get $$e^{0.61t}$$ would be a model for the population, $t$ being months.

Does this sound realistic?

Comment: I recommand to consider the second formula, with $r=0.7$.

Comment: Hmm..

They lay 100 eggs every 5 years, which means they lay about 1.7 every month.

If I change my interval to years, I should be able to say 1.7*12=20 and therefore:

$$20^5$$ would be the number in 5 years, but this is vastly different from typing $$1.7^{12*5}$$ Which should be the same? Why is this?

Comment: the mistake is that this is not 1.7*12, this is 1.7^12 (because you *multiply* by 1.7 12 times) ;)

Comment: Right, so $$1.7^{12*5}$$ would be the best estimate?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13890/discussion-between-mookid-and-user3200098)

Answer (score 1):

They are equivalent.

Let $e^k = 1+r$,
and the first becomes
$N_0 (1+r)^t$
and the second becomes
$N_0 e^{kn}$.

$n$ and $t$ just measure how far things have gone,
with $n$ usually having integral values
and $t$ usually having continuous values.
If $t$ is measured at equally spaced
intervals, then $t = a+bn$,
so 
$N_0(1+r)^t
=N_0(1+r)^{a+bn}
=N_0 e^a((1+r)^b)^n
=N_1 u^n
$
where
$N_1 = N_0 e^a$
and
$u = (1+r)^b$.